# Reverse engineer an ODE.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Consider the ODE,

$\dfrac{dy}{dx} = \dfrac{A y}{B + y} + C y$

where $A$, $B$ and $C$ are constants.

We have the boundary conditions,

$y_{(x=0)} = y_0$ and $y_{(x=n)} = y_n$, with $x$ ranging from $0$ to $n$.

Is there a way to reverse engineer that ODE to get the optimum value(s) of the constant $C$ given the values of $A$ and $B$? The solution of the ODE isn't essential; instead, the value(s) of $C$ that gives those boundary values is what matters.

Comment: Please roll back to the first post if not found okay.

Comment: @Narasimham, thank you. It looks better.

Answer (score 2):

Differentiate once, getting a second order ode. It is now a BVP ( boundary value problem) with two boundary conditions can be solved straightaway.

There is a shoot through technique to solve BVP, but I do not know if we also call that reverse engg.

Comment: You could also just add $C$ as second state component to $y$, with the equation $C'=0$.